# Filemaker Question. I need to create one table from the dataset of three tables

Tags: filemaker

So I have three tables

1.Studentdata - user id, username(1), fname, sname, location_id(2) ...

2.Recent_Logins - username(1), login date (In 6 months)

3. location - location_id (2), location_name

---

Relationships denoted by (1) & (2).

---

My Final table should have the usernames from Table 1 that do not show in Table 2 shown as follows:

---

Location_name

```
username, Fname, sname, email, number
```

---

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Stephen, Hey, I am brand spanking new to filemaker so I have tried nothing; my coding knowledge isn't great right now either tbh.

Comment: Well, what you want to do is a SQL JOIN. There are a lot of easy SQL tutorials available if you Google for them which will explain it easily and you won't have to wait around for an answer here. For example look on the W3Schools website.

Comment: @JoshuaVittachi If you're new to Filemaker, I recommend you join one (or more) of the forums dedicated to the platform. Stack Overflow is not a good place for this type of questions - in fact, your question is not about programming and as such is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do in FileMaker. No need to mess with any SQL join's that was suggested. It's purely point and click.

If you have your data in CSV or an Excel sheet, you can import your data directly into 3 tables in FileMaker and have it set up the fields automatically for you if you have a header column with names in your data.

If not, create the 3 tables manually in the Manage Database dialog and create the needed fields.
Move over to the Relationship panel and note the 3 boxes there. Each box represent a table you have just created. Each box show the fields in each table. Drag a line from each source field to a destination field in the other table(s).
That's pretty much it data-wise, for starters.
Press Ok to save the setup.

When you created the tables, 3 layouts were also created. Go to your main layout (Studentdata) and you should see your Studentdata fields there in a basic form.
Now you can add portals to the other 2 tables you have and be able to see and manipulate the related data.
Choose the portal tool form the toolbar or menu and draw out a portal. Select from which relationship you wish to show the data and choose your fields for display/data entry.

Save your layout and you should be set. You may need to adjust your relationships as to sorting order, create ability and so on.

You can create any number of layouts to represent the views of the data that you need, containing only the fields you are interested in.

You can make calculation fields that concatenate fields and do any kind of data manipulation.